# Bad bind variable error in store procedure - PL/SQL - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE demoStoreProc
(
  stringNums IN VARCHAR2   
)
AS
  stepCount NUMBER;

BEGIN

SELECT REGEXP_COUNT (stringNums ,',')+1 INTO :stepCount FROM "SYS"."DUAL" ;

END
```

So in the above stored procedure, the input is like

```
stringNums  = 12,13,14,15
```

and in variable stepCount I want to insert 4 , as there is 4 numbers are present

But I get this error:

> Bad Bind variable error for stepCount

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need that select

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE demostoreproc (
     stringnums IN VARCHAR2
) AS
     stepcount   NUMBER;
BEGIN
     stepcount := regexp_count(stringnums,',') + 1;
END;
/
```

But, what's the procedure doing anyway?

Rather, you may want a function.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE function demostoreproc (
     stringnums IN VARCHAR2
)  RETURN NUMBER AS
     stepcount   NUMBER;
BEGIN
     stepcount := regexp_count(stringnums,',') + 1;
     RETURN stepcount;
END;
/
```

Comment: it has some other logic too